# Input form Browse and get Folder Path and save in Text Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input

Is it possible to use a File Input within a form to just navigate to a Folder, and then select just that folder? I don't want to select a file within it, just the directory. I'd like to do this rather than have folks type in the entire path to the directory...

In otherwords:

User clicks [Browse] navigates to folder, clicks [OK] and the Browse Input retains the folder path.

I am creating a form for users to submit where they need access granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. There is no reason why a user would want to submit a *local* path to a *web* application anyway (besides some obscure local/intranet applications).

Comment: So is my only option to have them select a file, then strip that from the end of the path?

Comment: You will never receive the path on the server! All you will get is the filename (and the file contents of course).

Comment: Well, as I said - the path will never be sent to the server.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it at that. Thanks.